# margin of item position in QGraphicsView while resizing

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview

I am using graphics view framework for adding  items in run time into the view . items will be placed one below another like in vertical layout .

i always place my item at the start position of the scene (10,10) . but while resizing the view , the margin is getting adjusted . how to maintain the same margin every  time the view window is resized ?

i googled and found

```
QTransform Matrix(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1);
Matrix.scale(width() / sceneRect().width(), height() / sceneRect().height())
setTransform(Matrix);
```

helps in restoring the margin but it also shrinks the item based on the view height ration.

i always wanted to maintain the same item size even the view widget shrinks or expand. scrollbar has to appear .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QGraphicsView is a viewport onto a scene. You mention adding things into the view, which is not what you're doing; you're adding them to the scene, and then the view visualizes them. It may be that you understand that already, but just to be clear.

What I think it is that you're wanting to do is that as you resize the view, you want the pixel-to-scene relationship to stay constant and you want the view's origin to "stick" to the scene's origin. You mention a margin, but there isn't such a thing built into the scene/view relationship, so that's something you have to maintain yourself. In other words, you create a margin in the scene simply by not placing any items there, and then you have to translate the view so that the margin area within the scene is always within the view's viewport. It's the second part of this that I think you're having trouble with.

What I'd suggest is that you examine the view's transformation matrix as you resize the view. The m11 and m22 values are the scaling factors that show you how the view's pixels are mapped onto the scene coordinates, and the dx and dy are the translation factors that show you the relationship between the view's origin and the scene's origin.

Comment: thanks for the clear reply. Yes i am adding item to the scene only. say scene coordinate is (0,0,1000,1000) , i placed the item at QPoint(18,12) to maintain a margin gap. but when i resize the view window  these margins are increasing. the code lines i added will help maintain the margin but also scaling the item but i have to ignore item shrink .

Comment: I would have to write the code myself to be absolutely sure, but if you examine those transformation matrix values, I think you'll find that you want the scale factors (m11 and m22) to remain the same as you resize the view. I think you'll need to subclass QGraphicsView and override resizeEvent and in there, reset the QGraphicsView scale factors.

Comment: sure i will do it goug .. thanks you so much . i will update as per your recommendation  and reply you here .